# Reset to Default position with KineticJS

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I have the following circles in my game.  The player drags them into different locations in the game.  When the player selects, play again, I want the shapes to go back to the original position stated in the init function. How should I go about this? Thank you.

```
stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
   container: "container",
   width: 900,
   height: 550
});

shapes = new Kinetic.Layer();

function init() {
  circle1 = new Kinetic.Circle({
     x: stage.getWidth() / 3.2,
     y: stage.getHeight() / 3.2,
     radius: radius,
     fill: "blue",
     stroke: "black",
     strokeWidth: 4,
     name: "circle",
     draggable: true
});  

shapes.add(circle1)
stage.add(shapes)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store defaults in a separate variable, then use [`.setPosition( x, y )`](http://kineticjs.com/api-docs.php#docsNode) to reset it:

```
//store settings
var settings = {
     x: stage.getWidth() / 3.2,
     y: stage.getHeight() / 3.2,
     radius: radius,
     fill: "blue",
     stroke: "black",
     strokeWidth: 4,
     name: "circle",
     draggable: true
}; 

//use settings
circle1 = new Kinetic.Circle(settings);

//after move, reset using:
circle1.setPosition(settings.x,settings.y);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use the super handy setAttrs method like this:

```
circle1.setAttrs(settings);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is fairly old but I just solved something like this.

```
stage.removeChildren();
stage.setAttrs(stage.defaultNodeAttrs);
```

The stage.reset() doesn't work anymore, but this should do what you want.